# How to get an specific input using FormHelper

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Is there a way to do this with FormHelper:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i> Sign in</button>
```

I tried it using `$this->Form->end();` but it doesn't work as I wanted.

Comment: Will you state specifically what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 5):

Did you read the manual? Seems like this is what you're looking for;

[Creating buttons and submit elements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-buttons-and-submit-elements)

Something like this should probably work;

```
echo $this->Form->button(
    '<i class="icon-search"></i> Sign in',
    array('class' => 'btn', 'escape' => false)
);
```

Comment: Don't forget `'escape' => false` in the options array, or the `<i>` will get escaped and passed through to be visible on the final page. You might also want to check out the [Twitter Bootstrap Helper](https://github.com/loadsys/twitter-bootstrap-helper). (Full disclosure: the company I work for is responsible for that project.)

Comment: @beporter I originally added the escape option, but according to the documentation, for `button()`, the *default* is already 'false' (which is inconsistent with 'input' and the HtmlHelper). I didn't test my example though, documentation may be wrong

Comment: @thaJeztah Ah you are correct it's unnecessary, but it's probably a good habit to advocate. Doing it (perhaps unnecessarily) here will encourage proper usage elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
?>
<button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i> Sign in</button>
<?php
```

Remember - CakePHP is there to help make things easier.  If you have an already-simple task, there's no reason to complicate it.